# How to get value of a hidden input field in a servlet filter

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

In my filter I have generated a token and then stored the token in a
 session and bean.In the jsp page a hidden field is added with token
 value using bean.how can i compare the session and token value from
 jsp in my filter.my question is how to get the stored token value from
 jsp page.Is there any way that i can get the token for each page on
 request.Thank you

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Just use `request.getParameter()` the usual way? What exactly is your concrete problem in the filter?

Comment: Thanks,But i am in a situation not to revel my code. please give some brief idea of how to get values from jsp. It will be helpful

Comment: BalusC,consider I am Adding a value to hidden field like value="#{example.object}". now i want that "object" to be used in my filter

Comment: Still i am getting Error.i have added like request.getparameter(object).

Comment: My hidden field <h:inputhidden id="csrf" value="#{pc_example.value}"/>. In filter servlet i have called included like request.getparameter("value"). Is this correct

Comment: There's no name attribute on your input box, and you are using the wrong case for getParameter. Only old IE uses id as if its name.  Good browsers require a name attribute or they don't send the value of the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<h:form id="form_1">
    <h:inputHidden value="123" id="crsf" />
</h:form>
```

then 
HTML Output wiol be

HTML Output

```
<form id="form_1" name="form_1" method="post" action="..." enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input id="form_1:inputHidden_1" type="hidden" name="form_1:crsf" value="123" />
</form>
```

on filter you can use

```
request.getparameter("form_1:inputHidden_1");
```

AlsO YOU CAN USE

```
String crsf= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("crsf");
```

Comment: In my JSF name attribute for inputhidden is not available.Its throwing Error.

Comment: edited actually i used h:inputHidden you can continue with h:inputHidden like above or you can use standard <input name="crsf" type="hidden" value="crsftext" /> and get this in filter